# Обособление вводного слова в начале присоединительного оборота

Tags: присоединительный

> "Человек взрослеет в каком-нибудь определённом возрасте, например(,) в
> 18 лет..."

Почему в данном примере автор ставит запятую, ведь здесь вводное слово "например" стоит в начале присоединительного оборота?

Comment: Потому что об этом правиле мало кто знает. Его часто не соблюдают в статьях.

Comment: Это не статья. Это текст изложения ОГЭ по русскому.